# How to install wordpress theme in ubuntu localhost bitnami?

Tags: 16.04, wordpress, bitnami

I use ubuntu 16.04. I installed xampp and bitnami. I a newbie, so i don't know where wordpress theme local in ubuntu, so i try to upload zip theme via browser, like this: [image: screenshot]

Can somebody where document can show me data hostname, username and password? I don't know about this step. And tell me where is wordpress theme, plugin local in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using kali linux 2016.1. It's the same for me, I just tried to install themes manually in the `themes` folder on my LAMPP installation: `/opt/lampp/wordpress-4.5.1-0/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/`

And it's working: the theme is installed successfully. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i am 24 days late,
If you want to install wordpress on your server please follow the following steps.
1.Make sure you have already installed Ubuntu server edition and that you have root access to it. If you do, run the commands below to update your systems.

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove

2.Simply you have to install LAMP(Linux Apache MySql PHP).Now install apache.If you have already installed lamp then skip this part(Go to step 9).

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

3.Now try to restart it.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

4.Go to your browser check you have successfully installed it or not.

```
localhost/
```

If you have..then next

5.Installing mysql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

6.It will prompt for window for password..set your mysql password.

7.then try to start and enable it.

```
sudo systemctl start mysql
sudo systemctl restart mysql
sudo systemctl enable mysql
```

8.Securing your installation.

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

will ask..password..then several questions answer them in following type.

```
Change the root password? N
Remove anonymous users? Y
Disallow root login remotely? Y
Remove test database and access to it? Y
Reload privilege tables now? Y
```

9.Go to mysql.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

10.Create database for Wordpress.

```
CREATE database wordpress;
```

11.Create a new database user.

```
CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'new_password_here';
```

you may want to change username and password.

12.Grant permissions to created user.

```
GRANT ALL ON wpdb.* to wordpressuser@localhost;
```

13.Run this.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

exit;

BYE.
```

14.Installing PHP.and additional software which will require in further steps.

```
 sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

15.Download a zip file of wordpress separately by link.

```
https://wordpress.org/download/
```

16.Remove the files in the folder /var/www/html if any.

17.Extract the wordpress zip file into /var/www/html or copy extracted file into this html directory.This html directory is similar to the directory in xampp(Windows) i.e, htdocs.

18.Go to browser

localhost/wordpress

19. Select language
    Select db which we created.(wordpressuser,new_password)
    Give password.

20.Success.

Thank You.